# Flask-Dropzone automatic redirect url doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, routes, dropzone

I've tried to rewrite my code multiple times, and check where it stops working, i just can't figure out why it isn't working as it should.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,url_for
from flask_dropzone import Dropzone
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
dropzone = Dropzone(app)
app.config.update(
  DROPZONE_REDIRECT_VIEW = 'uploadCompleted',
)

@app.route('/',  methods=("POST", "GET"))
def index():
  if request.method == 'POST':
      # Upload file flask
      uploaded_img = request.files.get('file')
      ----Code Logic----
      return "200"
  return render_template('upload.html')
 

@app.route('/upload-completed',  methods=["GET"])
def uploadCompleted():
  ---stuff---
  return render_template('display.html')
    
 
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81)
```

upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {{ dropzone.load_css() }}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ dropzone.create('index') }}
    {{ dropzone.config(redirect_url=url_for('uploadCompleted')) }}
    {{ dropzone.load_js() }}
  </body>
</html>
```

display.html isn't important, it just doesn't get rendered even if it is a simple "return 'string' "
In theory once the file is loaded, dropzone should redirect to "/upload-completed", but it doesn't.
I "solved" the issue by manually placing a link to that route, but that's not what i want